# Build Json Object then relate the results to HTML table data

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, html-table

I pass out a ajax get which contains a parameter i.e. date added to db.

Java queries the DB for results of persons added on this date, and builds a JSON object for me like so:

```
{
  "resultdata" : { "rowsReturned" : "2", "fetchTime" : "180"}
  "row_1" : { "name" : "Larry", "sex" : "m", "age" : "26", "location" : "seattle" }
  "row_2" : { "name" : "Pedro", "sex" : "m", "age" : "22", "location" : "unknown" }
}
```

I can then return the JSON object as a String. I'd then like to dynamically build a table based on these results.

First of all is the JSON object correct for building a table?

The result data tells me how many rows and the time taken in milliseconds, followed by however many rows in that particular format.

I then want to create a table inside a specific div element once these results are returned to my browser on the fly with no page refreshes etc.

so Id expect Table headers with titles of each column - followed by you guessed it 2 rows.

How is the best way to go about doing this. I am familiar with jQuery, JSON is totally new to me and dealing with JSON in jQuery is something i'm keen on learning.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate your json.
Yours is not valid. It's missing some ',':

```
{
    "resultdata" : {
        "rowsReturned" : "2",
        "fetchTime" : "180" 
    }, // <--
    "row_1" : {
        "name" : "Larry",
        "sex" : "m",
        "age" : "26",
        "location" : "seattle" 
    }, // <--
    "row_2" : {
        "name" : "Pedro",
        "sex" : "m",
        "age" : "22",
        "location" : "unknown" 
    }
}
```

I've made a little [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MCyqp/) of one possible way how to loop through the json with for-in-loops

---

```
for (key in json) {
```

loops through the json and stores each key in the 'key' variable. 
in your case 'resultdata','row_1','row_2'.
So to access the data for each key you write json[key] which translates to json['row_1'] for example.
Now you do the same thing for the row_1 object with:

```
for(key1 in json[key])
```

key1 are now the keys in the row_1 object: 'name','sex',...

to access the data now you'll write json[key][key1] which would be json['row_1']['name'] for example.

of course it's advisable to give the keys meaningful names to avoid confusion like in my example:)

Comment: Thanks for the time you've put into this, its pretty much what i'm looking for. However if you have some time could you explain to me the deal with json[key][key1]..how the keys work for retrieving data from the json object you've parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Perfect. Get it now, seems silly of me to have been confused guess I'm having one of those days.

Comment: 1 more question say if i have a few keys in the arrays, but i want to output them to the table in a specific order, this might not be the order they are in in the json object. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: then you don't need the second loop. you can access them directly with json[key]['name'], json[key]['age']...

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON looks fine for building a table.

You'll want to use $.getJSON() to fetch the JSON data, as it will automatically parse the JSON into an object for you.  If you need the advanced features of $.ajax(), you can call $.parseJSON() on the returned data from the AJAX call and it will parse the JSON into an object.